# magento custom status as front end

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, sales

We are using Magento Marketplace

**My Controller**

```
if(count($trackingcol)==0){
    $trackingcol=Mage::getModel('mpshippingmanager/tracking')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldtoFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$orderid))
    ->addFieldtoFilter('tracking_number',array('eq'=>'canceled'));
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderid);
        if(count($trackingcol)==0){
            $product_order_id = $order->getIncrementId();
            $order->setStatus('complete');
            $order->save();
        }else{
            $order->cancel();
            $order->save();
        }
```

**.phtml**

```
<?php if(count($shipping_coll)): ?>
<?php if($item_status=="Ordered"): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/cancelorder',array('id'=>$mageorderid))?>">
      <button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Cancel Order') ?>" type="button" id="save_butn" >
      <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel Order') ?></span></span>
      </button>
    </a>
<?php endif;  ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($item_status=="Ordered"||$item_status=="Invoiced"){?>
    <button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Save Tracking Number') ?>" type="submit" id="save_butn" >
    <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Save Tracking Number') ?></span></span>
    </button>
<?php } ?>
```

It's for **front end**  While clicking this button status will be changed **front end** as well as **back end** also

How to add a more button called shipement if i click status also need to change shipped

My Custom Status is test

Cancel order Controller

```
public function cancelorderAction(){
            try{
                $orderid=$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
                $partnerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
                $collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection()
                                ->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid', array('eq' => $partnerid))
                                ->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid', array('eq' => $orderid));
                $flag=false;
                foreach($collection as $saleproduct){
                    $saleproduct->setCpprostatus(2);
                    $saleproduct->save();
                    $trackingcoll = Mage::getModel('mpshippingmanager/tracking')->getCollection()
                                ->addFieldToFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$orderid))
                                ->addFieldToFilter('seller_id',array('eq'=>$partnerid));
                    foreach($trackingcoll as $tracking){
                            $tracking->setTrackingNumber('canceled');
                            $tracking->setCarrierName('canceled');
                            $tracking->save();  
                            $flag=true;
                    }

                }
                $trackingcol=Mage::getModel('mpshippingmanager/tracking')->getCollection()
                                    ->addFieldtoFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$orderid))
                                    ->addFieldtoFilter('tracking_number',array('eq'=>''));  
                if(count($trackingcol)==0){
                        $trackingcol=Mage::getModel('mpshippingmanager/tracking')->getCollection()
                                    ->addFieldtoFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$orderid))
                                    ->addFieldtoFilter('tracking_number',array('eq'=>'canceled'));
                        if(count($trackingcol)==0){
                            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderid);
                            $product_order_id = $order->getIncrementId();
                            $order->setStatus('complete');
                            $order->save();
                        }else{
                            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderid);
                            $order->cancel();
                            $order->save();
                        }   
                    }
                if($flag==true){
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Order Cancled successfully..');
                }else{
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('You are not permitted for cancel this order..');
                }
            }catch(Exception $e){
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
            $this->_redirect('mpshippingmanager/shipping/invoice/id/'.$orderid);
        }
```

Comment: add `cancelorder` method too for better understanding

Comment: Check my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html for status test

```
   <?php if($item_status=="Ordered"): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/testorder',array('id'=>$mageorderid))?>">
      <button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Cancel Order') ?>" type="button" id="save_butn" >
      <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel Order') ?></span></span>
      </button>
    </a>
<?php endif;  ?>
```

method

```
public function testorderAction()
      {
           $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($id);
            $order->setData('state', 'test');
         $order->setStatus('test');
         $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('', false);
         $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
         $order->save(); 
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                    $this->__('The order state has been changed.')
                );
                $this->_redirectReferer();


     }
```

Comment: it showing error Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on a non-object in

Comment: Did you add method in controller

Comment: yes i added in controller file

Comment: update code add need credential to check also..

Comment: After update button not showing front end

Comment: it redirect  to next page and showing order id

Comment: there is space btween 'status' remove that

Comment: Ya thanks Status Changed. I need to redirect to same page and after change Status that button should be disabled also sucess message

Comment: How to disable button after change status

Comment: After updated code it shows error Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on a non-object

Comment: add old code add this `$this->_redirectReferer();` for redirect.

Comment: Ok thanks where i have to add Success message

Comment: `Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')
                           ->addSuccess('Order Updated Successfully');` add this before redirect code.. and kindly accept my answer..

Comment: can you please tell me how to disable button after change that shipement status

Comment: i already accept success message not working

Comment: `<?php if($item_status=="test"): ?> <?php endif;?>` add disabled inside the condition...

Comment: Ok thanks but success message not working

Comment: `Mage::getSingleton('core/session') ->addSuccess('Order Updated Successfully');` add this above code for admin area

Comment: Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session') ->addSuccess('Order Updated Successfully');
                $this->_redirectReferer();

Comment: `Mage::getSingleton('core/session') ->addSuccess('Order Updated Successfully'); $this->_redirectReferer();` replace with it..

Comment: Thanks for your help it's working fine +1 up vote for me

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33011/discussion-on-answer-by-qaisar-satti-magento-custom-status-as-front-end).

Comment: @QaisarSatti i have an problem after change status from seller dashboard side that order automatically removed from customer what is the problem

Comment: But if i click Complete state it showing customer dashboard

Comment: so don't  change the state just change the status.. i think problem with state.

Comment: How i changed that one only

Comment: i added two custom state 1st one not working but 2nd it's working fine what is the problem

Comment: which is working fine which or not?

Comment: Sorry it's working fine thanks for replied

Comment: Hi Button disabled not working

Comment: kindly post a new question and add html and which order state you want to disabled it